# Android Gradle custom task to run multiple assembles? Tasks are not dsistinct

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, gradle-task

I am trying to create a custom Gradle task for an Android project that will build both my flavours at the same time, rename the APK's and then copy them to a different folder.

The issue is I have another version of this task that is almost identical to the first one and when I run one task a part of the other task gets run too.

Here is my first task:

```
task buildWithVersion(type: GradleBuild) {
    delete "$buildDir/outputs/apk"
    delete "$buildDir/outputs/verionapks"
    tasks = ['assembleMyAppDebug', 'assembleMyAppRelease']
    android.applicationVariants.all { variant ->
        variant.outputs.all { output ->
            outputFileName = "${variant.name}_${variant.versionName}.apk"
        }
    }
    doLast {
        copy {
            from "$buildDir/outputs/apk"
            into "$buildDir/outputs/verionapks"
            include '**/release/*.apk'
        }
    }
}
```

And then the second one:

```
task buildWithoutVersion(type: GradleBuild) {
        delete "$buildDir/outputs/apk"
        delete "$buildDir/outputs/noneverionapks"
        tasks = ['assembleMyAppDebug', 'assembleMyAppRelease']
        android.applicationVariants.all { variant ->
            variant.outputs.all { output ->
                outputFileName = "${variant.name}.apk"
            }
        }
        doLast {
            copy {
                from "$buildDir/outputs/apk"
                into "$buildDir/outputs/noneverionapks"
                include '**/release/*.apk'
            }
        }
    }
```

I need two seperate tasks for this but the problem is when I run the first task then the apks get renamed as if the second task has run, so the apk's are renamed in this format "${variant.name}.apk", instead of the format I wanted in the first task. (The second task is after the first in my apps build.gradle file)

It looks like the android.applicationVariants.all loop gets run every time even though I only want it to run inside the task when I call it. Why is this? And is it possible to only have this run specifically when a specific task is run?